# Passing parameters on instantiation in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a little problem on passing parameter to an object when I instantiate it, let me explain it better:
I made an automatic turret in unity, it just aim an enemy and instantiate a missile that destroy the enemy. The turret works great, I'm having some problems only with the missile...
The missile is a game object with a script attached at, in this script I have only 1 public variable the type is "GameObject" and the name is "target", when (from the turret script) I instantiate the missile, I set the variable "target" equal to the enemy the turret is aiming at. 
Into the start function (missile's script) I rotate the missile towards the "target" and, incrementing the position of the missile it can hit the enemy.

Missile script:

```
public GameObject target;
private Vector3 targetPosition;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
  transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform);

    targetPosition = target.transform.position;

    //Rotation of the missile
    Vector3 difference = this.targetPosition - transform.position;
    float rotationZ = Mathf.Atan2(difference.y, difference.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0.0f, 0.0f, rotationZ);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
    float step = 1.5f * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move our position a step closer to the target.
    transform.position += transform.right * step;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Turret script

```
    public GameObject missile; //this is the missile prefab

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "enemy") //The turret is aiming an enemy
    {
        Target = collision.gameObject;
        StartCoroutine(openFire());
    }
}

    IEnumerator openFire()
{
        GameObject newMissile;

        newMissile = Instantiate(missile, this.transform.position, Quaternion.identity, GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform);
        missile.GetComponent<missileScript>().target = Target;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        if (Target != null)
            StartCoroutine(openFire());

}
```

Everything works fine, the problem arises when I have more than one turret: If I have two turret (turret A and turret B) and at the same time both turrets shoots to two different enemies, for some reasons, both missiles will have the same target. 
So, for example if the turret "A" shoots to the enemy "1", and, at the same time, the turret "B" shoots to the enemy "2", both missiles will go toward the same enemy.

I hope I was clear. Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Thanks.

-----FIXED-----

I simply have edited the variable "target" by public to private and I made a "setter" public method.
Sincerely I don't know why it fixed my problem...

Comment: Where's the code where you're setting the 'target' field?

Comment: My bad, I just edited the post

Comment: Ok, where is Turret setting the Target property?

Comment: Can you show us where are you setting the Target? It can be the problem.

Comment: Excuse me, I edited the post. To set the target I simply do "missile.GetComponent<missileScript>().target = Target;"

Comment: @JrAntonio man from where are you getting the "Target" game object? That's was my question.

Comment: Okay, updated, one more time

Comment: Something with your turret script can't be right in the example. You are instantiating a GameObject `missile` that is an empty object (as you declared it before), so it can't have a missileScript attached and you wouldn't be able to  acess it via `GetComponent<>()`. Can you please show the real code you are using?

Comment: What's the problem?  I said that the missile object has 1 script attached and 1 public variable: " The missile is a game object with a script attached at, in this script I have only 1 public variable the type is "GameObject" and the name is "target" "

Comment: Uh, I understand what the problem was, my mistake while copying the script, I updated the post

Comment: "missile" is the missile prefab, "newMissile" is the missile that I instantiate.

Comment: I simply have edited the variable "target" by public to private and I made a "setter" public method and it seems to work..
Sincerely I don't know why it fixed my problem...

Comment: Where is `Target` set? You have `<missileScript>().target = Target` but don't show us how `Target` is declared or assigned.

Answer (score 3):

You're overwriting your prefab:

```
missile = Instantiate(missile, ...)
```

You do declare a `GameObject newMissile` but you're not using it.

Second:

```
if (Target != null)
```

You're restarting the OpenFire method if the target isn't null...but you *still instantiate a missile!* You probably want to change this.